# Getting undefined reference to `hmac_sha1' in C

Tags: c

[This is my current workspace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGys2.jpg). I have the Headers in the same folder with the otp.c but whenever I compile and run it it returns an error telling me that hmac-sha1 is undefined. Hope someone can help me.

Comment: Please don't show images of text. Copy-paste text *as text* into your question. That includes your build command and the build output.

Comment: As for your problem, where is the missing function defined (implemented)? You need to build with that source file (or link with that library).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude using this command gcc otp.c -o otp -L/usr/lib -lcrypto; ./otp
for compiling and building

Comment: In the build command, try to move the library options from the end to the beginning.

Comment: That command is not what's shown in the image. Is the function defined (implemented) in the `crypto` library? Or in one of the other source files in your project?

Comment: And from  the image looks like you're running Visual Studio Code on Linux, and by default the C and C++ plugin doesn't build multi-file projects, it only builds the current source file *withput* libraries. I recommend [this VSCode with GCC on Linux guide](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/cmake-linux). Especially look at the section about [how to build using `tasks.json`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/cmake-linux) where you can list multiple files. Or even use something like Make.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Short Background**

Including a header file enables you to compile the source file into an object file by declaring the function.
However, to get an executable, you need to link the object files together whereby one function used in one object file may be defined (i.e. implemented) in another object file. When listing the objects for the linker, they must be arranged in order of dependency, e.g if a depends on b the a should appear before b on the command line (in case of circular dependencies please find a post on it).

**Solution**

The way you run `gcc` makes it first compile the sources into object files and link them. `otp.c` requires the function `hmac_sha1` is probably in `hmac-sha1.c` (I am guessing from the header file name) and so you should run:

```
gcc otp.c hmac-sha1.c -o otp
```

Note that `otp.c` depends on `hmac-sha1.c` hence the order.